# Splitting a text file into columns

Tags: python, string, text, split, text-files

Lets say I have a text file with this in it:

> 0100003 01000040100005 01004480100007 01000080100008 00004590100009 01000100100238 01001500100323 01005030100013

What I want the program to do is to press the "ENTER" key on my computer after counting out 15 characters. so far what I am supposed to do is take in a text file, reverse the output, and add it onto the original text. Then I need to split it up like this. i have done the code for reversing and adding on.
one could

```
f = open("rrEdges.txt", "rb")

s = f.read()

f.close()

f = open("newtext.txt", "wb")

f.write(s[::-1])

f.close()


with open ("rrEdges.txt", "r") as myfile:
    data=myfile.read().replace('\n', '')



with open ("newtext.txt", "r") as myfile:

    data += myfile.read().replace('\n', '')


temp ="" + data

open("rrEdges.txt","w").close()

text_file = open("rrEdges.txt", "w")

text_file.write(temp)
```

I have no idea how to approach this, but it should be very simple for some experienced users. So for example the final result would look like:

```
0100003 0100004

0100005 0100448

0100007 0100008

0100008 0000459

0100009 0100010

0100238 0100150

0100323 0100503

0100013
```

(but without the blank line between rows)

update: I have tried this

```
with open ("rrEdges.txt", "r") as myfile:

    data=myfile.read().replace('\n', '')

open("rrEdges.txt","w").close()

text_file = open("rrEdges.txt", "w")

string1=data+""

for i in range(len(string1)//15):

    text_file.write(string1[i*15:(i+1)*15])
```

Comment: What code have you got so far?

Comment: so far what I am supposed to do is take in a text file, reverse the output, and add it onto the original text. Then I need to split it up like this. i have done the code for reversing and adding on.

Comment: "What I want the program to do is to press the "ENTER" key on my computer" - unless you have a USB roboarm or something, that's going to be infeasible. It's clear that you want a line break, but still, thinking about it in terms of what a human at a keyboard would do can draw your attention away from the best approaches for the program to take.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
s="0100003 01000040100005 01004480100007 01000080100008 00004590100009 01000100100238 01001500100323 01005030100013"

print("\n".join([s[i:i+15] for i in range(0,len(s),15)]))

0100003 0100004
0100005 0100448
0100007 0100008
0100008 0000459
0100009 0100010
0100238 0100150
0100323 0100503
0100013
```

To write to a file just replace print with write:

```
with open("out.txt","w") as f:
 f.write("\n".join([s[i:i+15] for i in range(0,len(s),15)]))
```

output to the file looks like:

```
0100003 0100004
0100005 0100448
0100007 0100008
0100008 0000459
0100009 0100010
0100238 0100150
0100323 0100503
0100013
```

Comment: see the update if that makes any difference, I want to write to a text file

Comment: you can replace print with write

Comment: Let me try it i'll see how it goes

Comment: Cheers mate! Had to edit my old code a little but I made it work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
string1="0100003 01000040100005 01004480100007 01000080100008 00004590100009 01000100100238 01001500100323 01005030100013"
for i in range(len(string1)//15):
    print string1[i*15:(i+1)*15]
```

Comment: I want it to write it to a text file in that format.
see update at bottom of question

Answer (score 0):

You could use `re.findall` like below,

```
>>> s = "0100003 01000040100005 01004480100007 01000080100008 00004590100009 01000100100238 01001500100323 01005030100013"
>>> m = re.findall(r'.{15}|.+', s)
>>> for i in m:
...     print i
... 
0100003 0100004
0100005 0100448
0100007 0100008
0100008 0000459
0100009 0100010
0100238 0100150
0100323 0100503
0100013
```

Comment: Thanks, but Padriac answered first and his answer works! Would give best answer to all 3 if I could but unfortunately that is not possible.

Thanks for your help anyways!

Answer (score 0):

Adding onto Avinash's answer, one could use `re.finditer()` instead of `re.findall()` to loop over an iterator object instead of a list so that the overhead in making the list is reduced (from a performance point of view)